# Absolute Value Brackets Proof With Epsilon

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $|x−y| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then $x = y$.

Workings:

Proof:

Suppose for a contradiction that $|x−y| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ and $x \neq y$.

Then either $x > y$ or $y < x$.

Now I'm not too sure on what to do next.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If $x \neq y$, then let $\delta = |x-y|$ and note that $\delta>0$. Then pick $\epsilon = {1 \over 2} \delta$ to get a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\neq y$ then $|x-y|>0$. If we choose $\epsilon=|x-y|$ then we find:
$$|x-y|<\epsilon=|x-y|$$ which is impossible!

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x>y$, then $x-y>0$.  Choose $\epsilon$ so that $0<\epsilon<x-y$.